# Is mapred-site.xml totally useless in Hadoop 2 with YARN

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I found from many Hadoop related pages that in Hadoop 2 lots of mapred-site configurations are not working anymore and instead yarn-site.xml is used. But if so why still mapred-site.xml is maintained?

Answer (score 0):

For Hadoop v2, mapred-site.xml is still in use. You have a new property named **mapreduce.framework.name**, its value is the runtime framework for executing MapReduce jobs, it can be one of *local*, *classic* or *yarn*.  If you use *local*, your mapper and reducer processes will be executed in a same JVM, normally you do this for debugging purposes(only one reducer could be launched with *local* runtime). If you use *classic* the tradition MR v1 will be in action and MR v2 will be in action if you mention *yarn*.

When you are using YARN runtime for MapReduce jobs, your mapper and reducer processes will be spawned in containers, mapred-site.xml file could be used to specify system resources(e.g memory and v-cpu) for mapreduce containers. Remember that the upper limit for memory and v-cpu for containers is set in yarn-site.xml. Have a look at the following properties in mapred-site.xml.

- **mapreduce.map.memory.mb**
- **mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores**
- **mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb**
- **mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores**

[mapred-site.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)

[yarn-site.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)

Answer (score 0):

mapred-site.xml is still in use. Look [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml) for all default values.

Look [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html) for new properties in Hadoop V2 as a replacement for deprecated properties of Hadoop V1.

Few examples:

```html
mapred.map.child.env mapreduce.map.env
mapred.map.child.java.opts mapreduce.map.java.opts
mapred.map.child.log.level mapreduce.map.log.level
mapred.map.max.attempts mapreduce.map.maxattempts
mapred.map.output.compression.codec mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec
mapred.mapoutput.key.class mapreduce.map.output.key.class
mapred.mapoutput.value.class mapreduce.map.output.value.class
mapred.mapper.regex.group mapreduce.mapper.regexmapper..group
mapred.mapper.regex mapreduce.mapper.regex
mapred.map.task.debug.script mapreduce.map.debug.script
mapred.map.tasks mapreduce.job.maps
```